# Nuxt.js – Nuxt generate does not pass onclick parameter to component on 404 page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, http-status-code-404, nuxt.js, generate

I have a strange issue with my 404/index.vue which after `$ nuxt generate` generates my `404.html` file.
I am using a Btn component in my vue file which works on `index.vue` file but not on my `404/index.vue`.
It seems that it does not pass the onclick parameter to the component.

I think the following makes it more understandable:
404/index.vue

```
<script>
import { mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import Heading from '~/components/Heading/Heading.vue'
import Btn from '~/components/Btn/Btn.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    Heading,
    Btn
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(['defaultLang', 'currentLang']),
    ...mapGetters('data', ['getPageBySlug']),
    page () {
      return this.getPageBySlug('404')
    }
  },
  data: () => ({
    externalRoute: false
  }),
  beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    // check before route entering if we came from external or already from our app
    next(vm => {
      if (from.path === '/') {
        vm.externalRoute = true
      } else {
        vm.externalRoute = false
      }
    })
  },
  methods: {
    getBackPath () {
      return `/${this.currentLang !== this.defaultLang ? this.currentLang : ''}`
    },
    goBack () {
      // if we came externally we go to our root, else we go one route back in history
      if (this.externalRoute) {
        this.$router.push('/')
      } else {
        this.$router.go(-1)
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="Page">
    <Heading :level="1">{{ page.title }}</Heading>
    <Btn :click="goBack">{{ $t('error.link') }}</Btn>
  </div>
</template>
```

As you can see the goBack function should be passed to the Btn component.
After generation of the static pages the button is there (with the correct language error.link) but it would not do anything on click.

My button component looks like this: (I simplified it a bit to reduce to the important stuff here:

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Btn',
  props: {
    click: {
      type: Function,
      default: () => {},
      required: false
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style src='./Btn.scss' lang='scss'></style>

<template>
  <component
    class="Btn"
    v-on:click="click"
    <slot />
  </component>
</template>
```

I am using the same button component in my index.vue, which is rendered on the starting page. The Btn works nicely there (also after $ yarn generate and I cannot figure out what the difference would be. Somehow the Btn does not receive the onclick function on the 404 template.

If I add /404 to the router and I run the app locally, the Btn works.
It's really just isolated in the case when I generate the static pages that the Btn does not work on the 404 vue template anymore.

Any idea what the reason could be for this?